# Search function in DataGridView in C#?

Tags: c#, search, datagridview, dataset

I'm kind of at a loss here, but I can't seem to figure this out.

I have a DataGridView that reads from an .xml file and it displays about 2000 zip codes (and their corresponding IDs). Naturally, that's a bit much to read so I'm thinking about implementing a search function. Ideally, the user would be able to look for any number (zip code or ID) by entering it into a text box.  Something like this must surely be possible.

As a total beginner, I'm not sure how to go about this. Are there any helpful functions or expressions for this problem?

Comment: is it an xml datasource or a datatable ?

Comment: Apparently I used a DataSet. No DataSources and no DataTables.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use Like

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public List<DataRow> lstData { get; set; }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        loadgrid();
    }

    public void loadgrid()
    {
        DataTable dt = GetTable();
        List<DataRow> lstCollection = dt.AsEnumerable().ToList();
        lstData=lstCollection;
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

    static DataTable GetTable()
    {
        // Here we create a DataTable with four columns.
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
        table.Columns.Add("ZipCode", typeof(string));

        // Here we add five DataRows.
        for (int i=1; i<=100 ; i++)
        {
         table.Rows.Add(i, "Z00"+i);
        }

        return table;
    }


    public void SearchResult(string SearchParameter)
    {
        if (lstData != null)
        {

            if (SearchParameter != "")
            {
                if (lstData != null)
                {
                  List<DataRow> dt2 = lstData.FindAll(a=>a.ItemArray[0].ToString()== SearchParameter || a.ItemArray[1].ToString().ToLower() == SearchParameter.ToLower());
                  GridView1.DataSource = dt2.CopyToDataTable();
                  GridView1.DataBind();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                 GridView1.DataSource = lstData.CopyToDataTable();
                 GridView1.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            string SearchText = TextBox1.Text.ToString().Trim();
            SearchResult(SearchText);
    }

    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         GridView1.DataSource = lstData.CopyToDataTable();
         GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```